# Actively query the proximity sensor once?

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I need to get the current value of the proximity sensor (rather than implementing a continuous listener). On some devices, the first reported value will be a default value (e.g. "FAR") that isn't necessarily accurate, and actual values will only start appearing after the second or third reading. At the moment, I've implemented a 1-second `Handler` and use the last reported value (after the second has elapsed) as the "true" value, but this solution seems crude (and slow). Is there a better approach that works on all 4.0+ devices? I could simply count up until I've received 3 readings, but on some devices (e.g. GNex), the first value will be correct, and the value will only change after that if there is actually a change in the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what I did: 
You probably have an `if` statement on the listener - one logic flow for near and one for far.
Instead of waiting on the handler - do this:

```
if(near) {
   myHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnableForFar);
   myHandler.postDelayed(yourRunnableForNear,100);
else {
   myHandler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnableForNear);
   myHandler.postDelayed(yourRunnableForFar,100);
}
```

Notice that the inaccurate first reading(s) will immediately be followed by an accurate one, so the last one "wins".

This code works well if you didn't register sensors other than proximity. If you have a flow of readings from other sensors, than use a static flag (such as the `boolean near`) to trigger the handler calls only on state change.

**Elaboration:**
`yourRunnableForFar` and `yourRunnableForNear` - are placeholders that `implement Runnable` to hold your app logic on what to do when the proximity sensor returns "near" (`event.values[0] == 0`) or "far" (not 0).

`myHandler` is just any Handler you might created, or declare one just for this with  `Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

You might want to acquire a proximity lock on near, and release it and clear the listener on far. But this is app logic that might be completely different from app to app.

Comment: Hi uval, thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit on this (or post some more of your code)? What does `myHandler` and `yourRunnableForFar/Near` do?

Comment: elaborated a bit. This is basically a design pattern, and not a sample code per se. But it should work nonetheless.